# Angular material tabs with ui-router not properly updated with browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I'm using Angular material tabs together with ui-router to get some navigation tabs in my application. This all works like a charm but when I refresh the browser page the tab indicator is not properly updated. I've tried searching for a solution but couldn't find any that are different from what I'm using now. So what am I missing?

The tabs are inserted using a custom directive:

```
(function()
{ "use strict";

    angular.module("app").directive("ixpTabs", IXPTabs);

    /* @ngInject */
    function IXPTabs()
    {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "templates/components/tabs/tabs.html",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            controller: IXPTabsController,
            controllerAs: "tabCtrl",
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;
    }

    /* @ngInject */
    function IXPTabsController($scope)
    {
        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate()
        {
            for (var idx in vm.data)
            {
                var tab = vm.data[idx];
                tab.disabled = tab.disabled || false;
            }

            $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
            {
                // The selected tab index numbers from 0 but our tabs number from 1!
                vm.currentTab = toParams.tab - 1;
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

and template:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="tabCtrl.currentTab" md-theme="tabs">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="t in tabCtrl.data" ui-sref="{{t.route}}({{t.params}})" ng-disabled="t.disabled"><span translate="{{t.translate_id}}"></span></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

The ui-router states for the tabs are defined in the config of the module:

```
(function()
{ "use strict";

    angular.module("app.overview").config(OverviewConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function OverviewConfig($stateProvider)
    {
        $stateProvider
            .state("overview", {
                parent: "dashboard",
                url: "^/overview",
                templateUrl: "templates/features/overview/overview.html",
                controller: "OverviewController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                requireLogin: true,
                redirectTo: "overview.tab",
                redirectToParams: {
                    tab: "1"
                }
            })
            .state("overview.tab", {
                url: "/:tab",
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams)
                {
                    return "templates/features/overview/overview-tab" + $stateParams.tab + ".html";
                },
                controllerProvider: function ($stateParams)
                {
                    return "OverviewTab" + $stateParams.tab + "Controller";
                },
                controllerAs: "vm",
                requireLogin: true,
            });
    }

})();
```

The tabs themselves are defined in the controller:

```
(function()
{ "use strict";

    angular.module("app.overview").controller("OverviewController", OverviewController);

    /* @ngInject */
    function OverviewController()
    {
        var vm = this;

        vm.tabData = [
            {
                translate_id: "OVERVIEW.TABS.TAB_1",
                route: "overview.tab",
                params: {
                    tab: 1
                }
            },
            {
                translate_id: "OVERVIEW.TABS.TAB_2",
                route: "overview.tab",
                params: {
                    tab: 2
                }
            }
        ];
    }

})();
```